# SFMC Soap API Retrieve existing Tracking DataExtract

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, data-export, interaction

i am trying to retrieve an existing DataExtract filtering by CustomerKey but the API returns me a Status OK without any objects. Also tried to retrieve without filter bu i get the same result.
I am not sure if the API allows this action

Here are the Request and Response:

**Request:**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2018-01-03T14:40:01.066Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2018-01-03T14:45:01.066Z</u:Expires>
        </u:Timestamp>
        <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-ebf5cbfe-4228-46d9-b745-a6c469f1c1bc-1">
            <o:Username>#######</o:Username>
            <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">########</o:Password>
        </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ClientIDs>
                <ID>######</ID>
            </ClientIDs>
            <ObjectType>ExtractDefinition</ObjectType>
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                <Property>CustomerKey</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                <Value>49857226-AF7C-4B28-B659-1E90C15A4084</Value>
            </Filter>
        </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</s:Body>
```

**Response:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:06898b90-2ee8-4e26-9179-698b90353166</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:9fc2cafb-ab6b-402f-9d80-e89e20587c38</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-c781a3d4-cf9c-4676-967e-74abfbd18a6b">
            <wsu:Created>2018-01-03T14:40:02Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2018-01-03T14:45:02Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
        <RequestID>d0caeef0-36af-47d0-ac2c-ab0552c4d865</RequestID>
    </RetrieveResponseMsg>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't retrieve the actual data, it just starts the process to make it available in the system, where you can then act on it with a file transfer process to place it on the ftp server.